# Base64 -encoded images on Chrome don't save properly on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome

Our web-app has a contenteditable div we use for answering questions. Clients can paste images straight to the div (basic feature of 'contenteditable'), which turns pasted images into base64 strings.

We noticed that OSX Chrome handles the base64 decoding (encoding?) differently than other browsers. Our sample image turned into ~220 000 characters on Safari, but Chrome produced almost a million characters of base64 data.

This in turn causes an issue where the POST data is clipped, and only a part of the image is saved. All other content in the POST data that comes after the image are also clipped. The request is otherwise ok, Laravel saves the clipped data like any other and doesn't throw any errors in any logs.

PHP.ini settings should be fine (for example post_max_size=64M, php memory limit = 1024M), is there some settings in Laravel that could cause the clipping?

Comment: Memory limit set by php itself, on php.ini file. not by laravel

Comment: What browsers handle differently, is likely not the actual base64 encoding itself (that should produce the same output, with the _same_ input data) - but compression of the image content itself.